Spin-orbit coupling in atomic and nuclear physics. Difference in coupling and energy levels
In atomic physics, states with antiparallel $L$ and $S$ (generally speaking, I know there are exceptions, for now let's consider the simpler case, for example, let's limit ourselves to hydrogen or hydrogenoid atoms) have a lower energy when considering spin-orbit coupling. For example, the $^2 P_{1/2}$ state has a lower energy than the parallel-coupled state $^2P_{3/2}$.
But in the nuclear shell model, obviously inspired in the atomic shell model, lower energy states are those that have parallel $L$ and $S$, resulting in higher $J$ for lower energies. What causes this difference between two models that are based on the same ideas?

"antiparallel L and S" flips when the shell is closer to fully filled. Nuclear physics simply borrowed the term from atomic physics; there is no reason why the numerical specifics and behaviour would be copied over.

Do you have any nuclear shell model examples?

@naturallyInconsistent that looks like an answer, not a comment.

@JEB that little??? But I didn't even check if the OP's assertion is correct or not. Highly doubt.

I don't think the nuclear shell model is necessarily inspired by the atomic shell model. Their similarity results from binding fermions, where orbitals are going to appear according to orbital angular momentum quantum number, $l$.
As you know, the hydrogen atom in the Coulomb approximation factors into a spherical harmonic equation (where shells--labeled by $l$--are inevitable), and an $l$-dependent radial equation.
Since electromagnetism is "weak", spin-orbit falls under "fine-structure", and is a small correction. Moreover, we consider a single electron's interaction with a point nucleus (where the finite size of the nucleus is another fine-structure correction). I'm not an atomic physicist, but at some point the electron-electron interaction is filed under "screening" at the introductory level.
In nuclear physics, we get none of that. There is no central force, each nucleon interacts with other nucleons and spin-orbit
$$(\vec L \cdot \vec S)$$
is large in comparison to the $nn$-central force, as is spin-spin
$$(\vec\sigma_1 \cdot \vec\sigma_2)$$
and the non-central tensor force:
$$ S_{12}(\hat r) = 3(\vec\sigma_1 \cdot \hat r)(\vec\sigma_2\cdot\hat r)-
\vec\sigma_1 \cdot \vec\sigma_2 $$
and the other forces, "sigma minus L":
$$ \hat Q_{12} = \frac 1 2
\big[
(\vec\sigma_1\cdot\vec L)
(\vec\sigma_2\cdot\vec L) +
(\vec\sigma_2\cdot\vec L)
(\vec\sigma_1\cdot\vec L)
\big]
$$
and "sigma minus p":
$$(\vec\sigma_1\cdot\vec p)(\vec\sigma_2\cdot\vec p)$$
with
$$ \vec p = \frac 1 2 (\vec p_1 - \vec p_2) $$
$$ \vec L = \vec L_1 + \vec L_2 = \vec r \times \vec p $$
$$ \vec S = \frac 1 2 (\vec\sigma_1 + \vec\sigma_2) $$
Moreover, there are separate factors for the charge-independent terms:
$$ {\bf 1} $$
$$ \vec{\tau_1}\cdot\vec{\tau_2} $$
where $\vec \tau_i$ is the isospin of nucleon $i$. Moreover, there are $nnn$ and $nnnn$ forces that cannot be factored into combinations two-body forces (I have never seen how they are expressed mathematically, that I can remember--after getting a PhD in nuclear physics).
See http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Nuclear_Forces for a more complete discussion. A full discussion is not possible, as it is the current state of nuclear physics research.
Note: all that is an effective field theory. You get to do it all over again in baryon structure (quarks), where orbital excitations and spin-flip excitation lead to the $N^*$ resonances and the $\Delta$ resonance.
See https://pdg.lbl.gov/2023/tables/contents_tables_baryons.html
